# tomcat CATALINA_HOME environment variable issue

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables, catalina

I am having a weird problem on my server.
I am tryng to build `OpenGTS` so I am using `ant all`
now while building it gives an error which reads

```
optjars:

tomcat.home:

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/OpenGTS_2.4.2/build.xml:111: CATALINA_HOME environment variable has not been defined.
        (make sure CATALINA_HOME is defined and exported to the list of environment variables)
```

but I have already defined `CATALINA_HOME`
when i echo $CATALINA_HOME it gives `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.16`
It also shows in terminal in the environment variable list.
What might be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the mode of your OpenGTS folder in /usr/local/ ? if any thing other than 777 change it to 777